# VScode: Expected Comma Jsonc

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I setting my VScode settings.json. Here I found a bug, the VScode told me"**VScode: Expected Comma Jsonc**" Why?

```
          **"python.autoComplete.addBrackets": true,
            "python.autoComplete.extraPath": ["C:/python/Lib/site-packages"]**
```

The whole code as follow:

```
{
    "leetcode.defaultLanguage": "python3",
    "leetcode.endpoint": "leetcode-cn",
    "leetcode.workspaceFolder": "d:\\leetcode-exercise",
    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python"
    },
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
        **"python.autoComplete.addBrackets": true,
        "python.autoComplete.extraPath": ["C:/python/Lib/site-packages"]**
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe the '{}' is missing?The OK code as follow:

```
{
"leetcode.defaultLanguage": "python3",
"leetcode.endpoint": "leetcode-cn",
"leetcode.workspaceFolder": "d:\\leetcode-exercise",
"[python]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python"
},
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
   { "python.autoComplete.addBrackets": true,
    "python.autoComplete.extraPath": ["C:/python/Lib/site-packages"]
   }
]
```

}

By the way,does the '**' has any special function?I didn't retrieve its meaning.Can you tell me? Thanks!